# Show all divs and Select by category

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Kindly take a look at following URL : http://demo.templaza.com/w/vania/ you'll notice that you can view divs by relevance `All | Images | Videos | Post` all I have been trying to do is in simple HTML5 when the divs loaded in all section with all types of post then I can view each post by relevance just that quick as its being done on the above URL. Can anyone please provide me the direction to follow to accomplish this kind of functionality the way it filter images from all generated divs or the like.

I've been using class name for the div that use image = `class="image"` , video = `class="video"` etc. Just wondering how to create this filter.

Comment: Why don't you just copy-paste-debug their code ? Don't you have some coding of your own aside of your **'i want this'** question  ?  Google for 'isotope' library.

Comment: This awesome plugin I recommend to all: http://mixitup.io/

Comment: -1 because this question is not useful for future visitors. If that page goes away, no one will be able to understand your question hence it won't be helpful for anybody else but you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website you mentioned uses a jquery plugin called [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

http://jsfiddle.net/AYQET/

```
// cache container
var $container = $('#container');
// initialize isotope
$container.isotope({
  // options...
});

// filter items when filter link is clicked
$('#filters a').click(function(){
  var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Providing you direction to follow : **The website you mentioned uses a jquery plugin called isotope**

Comment: Thanks alot you guys are awesome!!!
Now as I know the right plugin I can easily code as per my need.. thanks alot.. Also I found this awesome plugin too.... http://mixitup.io/

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$('#FilterByAll').on('click', function(){
    $('div').show(); 
});

$('#FilterByImage').on('click', function(){
    $('div').not('.image').hide(); 
    $('.image').show();
});

$('#FilterByPost').on('click', function(){
    $('div').not('.post').hide();
    $('.post').show();
});
```

Should work for you.  See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wE8t7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the example URL you have given is using a plugin to do this (isotope).

But basically all you need to achieve this kind of smooth effect is a JS function that loops through all your div's and adds/removes a class of `hidden` depending on whether its classes match the button that is clicked.

```
$('div').not('.someClass').addClass('hidden');
```

or

```
$('div.someClass').removeClass('hidden');
```

Doing this by adding and removing a class `hidden` (instead of using JS for it all) means you can make use of CSS3 transitions to fade in/out your div's, optimising browser performance and allowing for more interesting transitions.

The CSS would look similar to:

```
//default div
div{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
//toggled class
div.hidden{
    opacity:0;
}
```

only a very basic example but: [CSS TRANSITION FILTER FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/qPv76/)